# SOAP WCF Service Call From a .NET Console Application

Tags: xml, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have a SOAP WCF service address and I want to access it from my console application.

I've added this service to my console project from service reference and this generated a config file as follows

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ZINTWS0018binding">
                    <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="ZINTWS0018binding_SOAP12">
                    <mtomMessageEncoding />
                    <httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://34sapqa6.arkas.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zintws0018/120/zintws0018service/zintws0018binding"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ZINTWS0018binding"
                contract="SAPServiceRef.ZINTWS0018" name="ZINTWS0018binding" />
            <endpoint address="http://34sapqa6.arkas.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zintws0018/120/zintws0018service/zintws0018binding"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ZINTWS0018binding_SOAP12"
                contract="SAPServiceRef.ZINTWS0018" name="ZINTWS0018binding_SOAP12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

I've assigned username and password too like;

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "***";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "***";
```

When I'm trying to access this service I'm getting the error as follows;

Do you have a suggestion? I'm doing mistake at which point?
Thank you.

`{"The content type text/xml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wsdl:definitions targetNamespace=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style\" xmlns:wsdl=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/\" xmlns:wsoap12=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/\" xmlns:http=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/\" xmlns:mime=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/\" xmlns:tns=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style\" xmlns:wsp=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy\" xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\" xmlns:n1=\"urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions\"><wsdl:documentation><sidl:sidl xmlns:sidl=\"http://www.sap.com/2007/03/sidl\"/></wsdl:documentation><wsp:UsingPolicy wsdl:required=\"true\"/><wsp:Policy wsu:Id=\"BN_BN_ZINTWS0018binding\"><saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer uri=\"http://xml.sap.com/2006/11/esi/esp/binxml\" xmlns:saptrnbnd=\"http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding'."`}

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you can access the address in a browser. If not then that might point to an issue...

Comment: Yes, I can access to the address when I check it over SOAPUI